# Plotting Sankey Plot based on Temporal Sequence in R

Tags: r, visualization, sankey-diagram

I'm trying to plot a sankey plot use sequential / temporal data. I'd like the sankey plot to have 5 columns total (V1:V5) where all of the values in V1 can then flow to V2 and ect. I'm having a hard time because the events have the same name, even though they are not the same event because of the temporal difference. I have included a snippet of my data below.

```
#my dataframe
df <- data.frame(
  V1 = c("I", "X", "I", "I", "I", "I"),
  V2 = c("I", "X", "I", "I", "B", "B"),
  V3 = c("I", "X", "P", "I", "T", "I"),
  V4 = c("FINISH", "FINISH", "I", "I", "I", "I"),
  V5 = c("FINISH", "FINISH", "FINISH", "FINISH", "CONTINUE", "FINISH")
```

Comment: what does the rest of your code look like to generate the sankey?